# Java: Creating a Tree based on Morse Code

Tags: java, object, if-statement, tree, nodes

Given the alphabet and a morse code value for each letter...

```
a._
b_...
c_._.
d_..
e.
f.._.
```

I'm attempting to create a tree, finding the position for a letter in the tree by scanning the code, and branching left for a dot and branching right for a dash.

I've created a node class with the typical `numberNode left` and `numberNode right` variables along with `morseCode` and `letter`. Here's my function.

`aList` is an arraylist of created nodes read in from a file. `rootNode` is the root of the tree, having no set `letter` or `morsecode`.

```
    public static void createTree(ArrayList<numberNode> aList, numberNode rootNode)
{
    for (numberNode n : aList)  //for each numberNode in aList
    {
        int lengthOfCode = n.getmorseCode().length()-1;  //get the length of the morsecode
        numberNode currentNode = rootNode; //sets currentNode to the rootNode at first
        for (int i=0; i<lengthOfCode; i++) 
        {
            char c = n.getmorseCode().charAt(i); //for each char in morsecode until it gets to the end
            if (c == '.')
            {
                if (currentNode.getleft() = null) //if currentnode left is null
                {
                    numberNode newLeftNode = new numberNode(); //create new node
                    currentNode.setleft(newLeftNode); //set current node left to the new node
                    if (i == lengthOfCode)
                    {
                        currentNode.setleft(n); //if end of morse code, set the current node left's to n
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        currentNode = newLeftNode; //else change current node to the newly created leftnode
                    }

                }
                else //if current node left is not null
                {
                    if (i == lengthOfCode)
                    {
                        currentNode.setleft(n); //if at end of morse code
                    }
                    currentNode = currentNode.getleft(); //if not at end set current node to current node's left

                }

            }
            if (c == '_')
            {
                if (currentNode.right() =null)
                {
                    numberNode newRightNode = new numberNode();
                    currentNode.setleft(newRightNode);
                    if (i == lengthOfCode)
                    {
                        currentNode.setright(n);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        currentNode = newRightNode;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    if (i == lengthOfCode)
                    {
                        currentNode.setright(n);
                    }
                    currentNode = currentNode.getright();

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Couple questions I have...

Is my algorithm at least correct?

Is there an alternate way of doing this without it being so ugly?

If you need to see any more of my code please don't hesitate to ask. Thanks for your time, I truly appreciate it!

EDIT: Currently runs, but getting the current output

```
    a
null
null

b
null
null

c
null
null

d
null
null
```

Any ideas on what's going wrong?

EDIT#2: Added my class

```
    class numberNode
{
    String morseCode;
    String letter;
    numberNode left;
    numberNode right;
    int occupied;


        public numberNode()
        {
            this.occupied=0;
            left = null;
            right = null;
        }
        public void setmorseCode(String aCode)
        {
            morseCode = aCode;
        }

        public String getmorseCode()
        {
            return morseCode;
        }

        public void setletter(String aLetter)
        {
            letter = aLetter;
        }

        public String getletter()
        {
            return letter;
        }

        public void setleft(numberNode aNode)
        {
            left = aNode;
        }
        public numberNode getleft()
        {
            return left;
        }

        public void setright(numberNode aNode)
        {
            right = aNode;
        }
        public numberNode getright()
        {
            return right;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `currentNode.getleft()` returns a null, then trying to call equals on it will give you the NPE.  You test for null with ==:

```
if (currentNode.getleft() == null) ....
```

Comment: thanks for the input, it's currently running, but isn't giving me the output I would think it would. I have included my class in the example as well now